# Crear elementos cuyos id no sean iguales

Tags: php, html, while

He escrito un código que mientras se cumpla una condición cree elementos. El problema es que estos elementos creados tienen todos el mismo id. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que tengan id diferentes? Muchas gracias de antemano. Es lenguaje PHP.
Aquí les dejo el código:

```
while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        $salida.="<tr>
                <td><button id=fila1>".$fila['nombre']."</button></td>
                </tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Antes del `while` agrega un `$i=0;` y luego modifica: `<button id=".++$i.">".$fila['nombre']."</button>`

Comment: Si los datos que estas obteniendo desde la base de datos, tienen un campo único ( id por ejemplo ) puedes añadir ese id al id del botón, para que de esa manera, cada elemento tenga un id diferente, pero también, en caso de tener que hacer algo con los elementos, o saber a que fila correspondía, etc, tendrás la información ahí.
Por ejemplo:
<td><button id=fila1".$fila['id'].">".$fila['nombre']."</button></td>

Comment: @Ibai A.  Gracias. No me había dado cuenta.

Comment: @aeportugal Que tonto soy. Y yo rompiéndole la cabeza cuando con simples variables hubiese sido más fácil. Muchisimas gracias.